# Can't get ORB algorithm to match my images

Tags: python, opencv

I've tried to use ORB algorithm on these images. The code works but i can't get enough keypoints to match the images. How can i make it work?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('cards4/eightofspades100.png', 0)
img2 = cv2.imread('cards4/deck 4.png', 0)

cv2.imshow('img1',img1)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

#des1 and des2 are arrays of 500 features and 32 values

imgKp1 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img1, kp1, None)
imgKp2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img2, kp2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

good = []

# m and n because k = 2 and k is the number of features
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance <1*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, flags = 2)


cv2.imshow('Kp1', imgKp1)
cv2.imshow('Kp2', imgKp2)
#cv2.imshow('img1', img1)
#cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
#cv2.imshow('img3', img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[eight of spades](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5GYa.png)

[deck of card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgzV7.png)

Comment: I do not think feature matching is the way to go for this situation. Your template is too small and matches with too many features to many parts of your main image. I suggest you use templateMatching.

Comment: I did it with template matching. I just want to know if there is  a way to make this  work with ORB. I mean the images are small but not that small

Comment: Feature matching works from corners as the features. Your template has only 3 good corners. On the spade. But your image has lots of spades. So I do not think ORB or any feature matching algorithm is going to work well.

Comment: okay so what would be other way to detect cards?

Comment: Why do you need another way?

Comment: You could consider shape matching with Hu Image Moments. See for example https://learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/. But you would have to do that for every patch in the input image by shifting one pixel at a time.  However, I do not think it would be as sensitive as template matching using correlations.

Comment: well this one deosn't work and you said template matching cannot work with rotations and scaling and i want to explore the different techincs that are out there. I'll check out Hu image moments and if you have any other ideas please let me know

Comment: everyone has problems with ORB. don't use it. use AKAZE or SIFT. -- there's not much feature-y stuff on those pictures. don't expect much.

Comment: Their are versions of template matching that can handle rotations and scaling. See https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.730.9105&rep=rep1&type=pdf and https://digitalcommons.lsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5237&context=gradschool_theses and https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/registration/plot_register_rotation.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Template matching using cv2.matchTemplate():

```py
import wizzi_utils as wu  # pip install wizzi_utils
import cv2


def match():
    src = wu.cvt.load_img(path='cards4/deck 4.png')
    template = wu.cvt.load_img(path='cards4/eightofspades100.png')

    # reduce images size to 30% (too big to see results)
    # works also without resizing - just to visualize
    reduce_factor = 0.3
    src = wu.cvt.resize_opencv_image(img=src, resize=reduce_factor)
    template = wu.cvt.resize_opencv_image(img=template, resize=reduce_factor)

    # display on the right side
    wu.cvt.display_open_cv_image(img=src, ms=1, title='src', loc='top_right')
    wu.cvt.display_open_cv_image(img=template, ms=1, title='template', loc='bottom_right')

    # convert to gray scale
    src_g = wu.cvt.BGR_img_to_gray(bgr_img=src)
    template_g = wu.cvt.BGR_img_to_gray(bgr_img=template)
    t_height, t_width = template_g.shape

    # different methods
    methods = [cv2.TM_CCOEFF, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, cv2.TM_SQDIFF]
    print('matching:')
    for method_idx in methods:
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(src_g, template_g, method_idx)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
        print('\tfor method_idx {}: min_loc={}, max_loc={}'.format(method_idx, min_loc, max_loc))
        location = min_loc if method_idx in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF] else max_loc
        bottom_right = (location[0] + t_width, location[1] + t_height)

        # just for drawing the result
        src_copy = src.copy()
        cv2.rectangle(img=src_copy, pt1=location, pt2=bottom_right, color=wu.pyplt.get_BGR_color('r'), thickness=2)
        wu.cvt.display_open_cv_image(img=src_copy, ms=0, title='method idx {}'.format(method_idx), loc='top_left')

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return


def main():
    match()
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wu.main_wrapper(
        main_function=main,
        seed=42,
        ipv4=False,
        cuda_off=False,
        torch_v=False,
        tf_v=False,
        cv2_v=False,
        with_pip_list=False,
        with_profiler=False
    )
```

[image]